# How to change the Blender Proxy File Location

Tags: video-sequence-editor

While video editing theres this thing called proxy and basically it makes a folder where the video you put into blender is at. I have a temporary folder which holds all cached data and autosaves. And I want to change where those proxy folders are made because they are everywhere, making them difficult to organize across my computer. Is there anything I can do that will change the location of those folders?

Comment: Have you tried creating a file that's saved locally to your computer and then saving your projects in that through Blender?

Comment: @Starry-EyedDonut, yes I have I have a whole folder dedicated to my blender projects. It’s when a video is in a different location and put into the blender sequence editor it makes a folder called **“BL_Proxy”** and that folder is in the same location as the video that was dragged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Sequencer Editor* properties (side panel N) > *Proxy > Proxy Settings* >

- change *Storage* from *Per Strip* to **Project** type
- set *Directory* to **//BL_proxy/**
  (or use any other name folder, just start with double slash if you want to generate folder in directory of your blend file ... or set a full path if you want all proxies of any blend file to be stored at a specific directory)

[image]

If you want to have it set for any newly created blend file - go to header menu *File > Defaults* and **Save Startup File**.

Comment: Yep it works. Thanks!

Comment: Great it helped :)